# For matrices, how to deduce $AB$ using $A^2, B^2, (A+B)^2$ and so on (any matrix squares)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume matrix square can be calculated in $O(n^c)$ time, show that any square matrix multiplication can be done in the same $O(n^c)$ time.

The problem I got is that $AB$ and $BA$ always occur together with same coefficients. So that I cannot get $AB$ only.

Thanks in advance and any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot recover $AB$ from the values of $A^2, B^2$ and $(A+B)^2$. For instance, suppose
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1},
\ B=\pmatrix{1&x\\ &-1}.
$$
Then $AB$ depends on $x$ but $A^2=B^2=I$ and $(A+B)^2=4I$ are constant matrices.

**Edit.** Incidentally, [WolframAlpha does not seem to compute $(A+B)^2$ correctly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-1%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B0,-1%7D%7D)%5E2). I don't know why.

Comment: A very nice example (+1, of course). Just commenting on W/A part. For its own reasons Mathematica computes a square of a list (=a vector) by squaring all the elements of a list. Same with matrices, because to it a matrix is a list of lists. You need to use "a dot product" to coerce it to multiply matrices. So [do this instead](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28{{1,0},{0,-1}}%2B{{1,1},{0,-1}}%29.%28{{1,0},{0,-1}}%2B{{1,1},{0,-1}}%29)

Comment: WolframAlpha (really Mathematica) applies functions to lists elementwise, so $f(x) = x^2$, then $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$.  Since matrices are lists of lists, the same principle applies, via folding.  Try `MatrixPower[A,2]` instead.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and Sammy Black  I see. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clear in the first time, and it might be misleading when asking "using the square of same-size matrices" -- it's hard to ask the proper question before get an answer. Anyway, I have post my solution and edit the word used in the question statement.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

I got inspired from a "step-by-step" question [here](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~ywu/Courses/CSE3500F13/HW3.pdf) (Q4 c).

We can first argue that since matrix multiplication needs to handle at least $n^2$ numbers, therefore it is at least of order $O(n^2)$, that is, $c≥2$.

Then for any $n*n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, let $X, Y$ be two $2n*2n$ matrices, such:
$$X=\left[\begin{array}{l}A&0\\0&0\end{array}\right], Y=\left[\begin{array}{l}0&B\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$

Then we have 
$$XY + YX = \left[\begin{array}{l}0&AB\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$
Combined with that

$$(X+Y)^2-X^2-Y^2 = XY + YX$$

We can get $AB$ using three squares: $A+B, A$ and $B$.

Since it cost $O(n^c)$ to multiply two $n*n$ matrices, it takes $(2*n)^c=2^c*n^c$ to calculate either of $XY + YX, X^2$ and $ Y^2$.

Hence in total, this method is of $O(n^c)$.

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks for your follow up. I understand that visitors to this post might expect answers on "how to get back AB using those squares", but indeed that is not my intention and does not solve my original problem. But it seems that most of visitors is of little interest to the initial question, so I cancelled the acceptance of my answer to make it fair and leave it to visitors' judgment.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked by the OP -at least the part in the TITLE- is interesting (Unfortunately, his answer is not...). user1551 , using an ad hoc couple $(A,B)$, showed that, generally speaking, $AB$ cannot be recovered. Yet, generically, it seems to me that we can recover $AB$ and even more.

Consider generic matrices $A_0,B_0$ (for example, randomly choose them) and give, to a solver, the matrices $A_0^2,B_0^2,(A_0+B_0)^2$. Then, numerical simulations seem to show that the system $X^2=A_0^2,Y^2=B_0^2,(X+Y)^2=(A_0+B_0)^2$ has only two solutions: $(A_0,B_0)$ and $(-A_0,-B_0)$. In particular, $A_0B_0$ can be recovered; it remains to prove it...

EDIT. Answer to @ Tianchi Cai. Def: Let $(a_{ij})_{ij},(b_{ij})_{ij}$ be independent commuting indeterminates over $\mathbb{Q}$; in other words, the $(a_{ij})_{ij},(b_{ij})_{ij}$are elements of transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and they are mutually transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the matrices $A,B$ are called "generic matrices" over $\mathbb{Q}$.

In particular, $A,B$ have distinct non-zero eigenvalues in the algebraic closure $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}((a_{ij})_{ij},(b_{ij})_{ij})$, $AB\not= BA$, $A,B$ have no common eigenvectors,...

Comment: Consider two $2*2$ matrices $A = B = \left[\begin{array}{l}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right]$. Then we have $A^2 = B^2 = (A+B)^2 =  \left[\begin{array}{l}0&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]$. However, this system of three equations has more than two solutions, for example, any multiple of $A, B$ can be a set of solution. This question might appear to be trivial at a first glance, but indeed it worths more thinking.

Comment: @ Tianchi Cai , your matrices $A,B$ are not generic.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "generic"? Are you looking for a category or a specific kind of A, B that can recover A*B from squares?